# Не хочет инициализироваться поток

Tags: c++

Каждый параметр абсолютно верен, но почему-то вызывается exception в std::invoke.
Код:
Вызываемая функция:

```
void AutoSendFunc(
bool& CloseThreads,
char* Request,
int delay,
void(*ProcessFunc)(request),
void(*sendRequest)(char*&, char*))
{
    while (!CloseThreads)
    {
        char* ptr;
        sendRequest(ptr, Request);
        ProcessFunc(request(std::string(ptr)));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
        delete ptr;
    }
}
```

Попытка вызова потока:

```
void sendRequest(char*& recvdest, char*send)
{

}
...
std::vector<std::pair<
    std::pair
        <std::string,
        int>,
    void(*)(request)>> Requests;
...
#define Request Requests[i].first.first
        char* request = new char[Request.size()+1];
        memcpy(request, Request.c_str(), Request.size());
        request[Request.size()] = 0;
#undef Request
    std::thread thread
    (
        AutoSendFunc,
        CloseThreads,
        request,
        Requests[i].first.second,
        Requests[i].second,
        &sendRequest
    );
```

Вывод:

```
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(238): error C2672: "std::invoke": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(246): note: выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1,2,3,4,5>(std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2,3,4,5>)"
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>>>,
1>            _Ty=size_t
1>        ]
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(245): note: выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1,2,3,4,5>(std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2,3,4,5>)"
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>>>,
1>            _Ty=size_t
1>        ]
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(242): note: при компиляции функции-члена "<Нет данных>" класса класс <Нет данных>
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(230): note: выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept"
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>>>
1>        ]
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(257): note: выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон класс "std::_LaunchPad<_Target>"
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>>>
1>        ]
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thread(46): note: выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "void std::_Launch<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)"
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>,
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\alleksh\source\repos\netlib\netlib\netlib.h(152): note: выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "std::thread::thread<void(__cdecl &)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)),bool&,char*&,_Ty2&,void(__cdecl *&)(request),void(__cdecl *)(char *&,char *),void>(_Fn,bool &,char *&,_Ty2 &,void (__cdecl *&)(request),void (__cdecl *&&)(char *&,char *))"
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty2=int,
1>            _Fn=void (__cdecl &)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *))
1>        ]
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(237): error C2893: Сбой при специализации функции-шаблона "unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)"
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(237): note: Со следующими аргументами шаблона:
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(237): note: "_Callable=void (__cdecl *)(bool &,char *,int,void (__cdecl *)(request),void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *))"
1>d:\mvs\ide\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\thr\xthread(237): note: "_Types={bool, char *, int, void (__cdecl *)(request), void (__cdecl *)(char *&,char *)}"
```

Comment: "...но почему-то вызывается std::invoke"? А что по-вашему должно вызываться?

Comment: `#define Request Requests[i].first.first`??? Это что за монструозная конструкция? Почему бы не сделать просто `const std::string &Request = Requests[i].first.first`?

Comment: "Каждый параметр абсолютно верен"? А как объявлено `CloseThreads` в вызывающем коде?

Comment: 1) Ну, по-моему должно все работать правильно.     
2) Не знаю, мне так удобнее.    
3) CloseThreads объявлен как bool.

Comment: Так а что именно не работает? **В чем ваш вопрос вообще?** Почему вы решили, что `std::invoke` не должно вызываться?

Comment: Если `CloseThreads` объявлен как `bool`, значит каждый поток получает ссылку на свою независимую копию `CloseThreads`, которая не имеет никакого отношения к вашему `CloseThreads`. Я уверен, что это совсем не то, что вы хотели получить. А вы нам рассказываете, что "каждый параметр абсолютно верен"...

Comment: Я не так выразился, извините. У меня exception в std::invoke

Comment: Exception выброшенный откуда именно? (Почему мы должны вытягивать эту информацию клещами?)

Comment: Сейчас добавлю. Еще раз извиняюсь.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь. Я уже исправил код, данной ошибки не возникает.
(я заменил bool& на bool* и передаю теперь указатель)

Comment: Во-первых, я вижу ошибки компиляции, а вы нам почему-то рассказываете про какой-то "exception". Во-вторых, ошибка именно в способе передачи `CloseThreads`. См. мой ответ.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. И еще раз извиняюсь, теперь уже за использование неверных терминов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана именно неправильной передачей в поток аргумента `CloseThreads`. Если вы хотите передать аргумент для параметра типа "ссылка", то передавать следует именно `std::ref`

```
std::thread thread
(
    AutoSendFunc,
    std::ref(CloseThreads),
    request,
    Requests[i].first.second,
    Requests[i].second,
    &sendRequest
);
```